# GET_LOCK in MYSQL waits more than timeout

Tags: php, mysql, mutex, locks

I am trying to use the MYSQL locks to build a mutex in php.

I have got one process per user and I want that each process will be executed one at time.

I want that if one process for user "my_user" checks that exists other process with "my_user", the new process takes other way, for example a piece of code that reports that the process for this user is already executing.

I have got this test code and I see that the GET_LOCK function waits more than 1 second in a second instance, why?

```
//name of the lock
$user = "my_user";

//calling get_lock with 1 second as timeout
$i_sql = "SELECT GET_LOCK('$user', 1)";
if($debug) file_put_contents($logfile, "$i_sql \r\n", FILE_APPEND); 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $i_sql);
if (!$result) {
  echo "Could not successfully run query ($i_sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
  exit;
}

echo "Adquired ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br>";

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
print_r($row);
echo "<br>";
$count = 0;
//stay here 10 seconds
while($count < 2){
    sleep(5);
    $count++;
}

//release the lock  
$i_sql = "SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('$user')";
if($debug) file_put_contents($logfile, "$i_sql \r\n", FILE_APPEND); 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $i_sql);
if (!$result) {
  echo "Could not successfully run query ($i_sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
  exit;
}
echo "Release ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br>";

mysqli_close($con);
unset($con);
```

Output:

**Process 1** launched at 10:00:07:

```
Adquired 2013-07-08 10:00:08
Array ( [0] => 1 [GET_LOCK('my_user', 1)] => 1 )
Release 2013-07-08 10:00:18
```

**Process 2** launched at 10:00:08:

```
Adquired 2013-07-08 10:00:18
Array ( [0] => 1 [GET_LOCK('my_user', 1)] => 1 )
Release 2013-07-08 10:00:28
```

Comment: Print date also just before running queries e.g. `echo "GET_LOCK ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br>";` and `echo "RELEASE_LOCK ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br>";`. It might be you are not running those processes in parallel.

Comment: Yes, the process 1 blocks the process 2 until the second 18. It works yes, process 1 and process 2 are not running in parallel, they are running , but I want that if the timeout is gone then

Comment: Yes, the process 1 blocks the process 2 until the second 18. It works yes, process 1 and process 2 are not running in parallel, they are running in order (one-by-one). But, that i want is that if the timeout is exceeded then execution goes ahead and that the query returns 0 indicating that the lock has not catched.